# 404 after restarting local IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have .NET application installed on my local IIS instance. 
I had some problems with rebuilding files so I turn off IIS and logged off my user and then after login again, I turned my IIS on.

But after that I get 404 on every website. 
All app pools and websites are on. 
I tried restarting IIS. 
Nothing helps

Is there is anything else I can do?

Comment: Hi Radoslaw,
Can you please try to hit just localhost (http://localhost/) from a browser and tell what are you getting?

Comment: What does the log on the server say?

Comment: There are many reasons why. Files in the wrong directory? The application pool not being set to Integrated Pipeline?

Comment: @RangaDewasinghe 
I checked http://localhost/, it returns 404 as well

Comment: @RadosławKunecki This can happen in various situations. So first you need to configure windows event viewer explore the exact error caused.
Please follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524984(v=vs.90).aspx) for more information.
LMK what it says.

Comment: @RangaDewasinghe the event viewer says:
The World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW Service) did not register the URL prefix https://*:443/SITENAME/websites/PORTALNAME for site 1. The site has been disabled. The data field contains the error number.

Comment: @RadosławKunecki It seems like you are facing into an application URL binding issue. So if you can please update the question with C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config files  <sites> section  plus the URL you are currently trying to hit?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed issue by replacing corrupted applicationHost.config with archived one.

I followed procedure from following link:
https://jshidell.com/2012/03/27/fixing-corrupted-applicationhost-config-file-in-iis-7/